# is good way to include external class into a method?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm developing a MVC model. In router class , I include needed controllers according to the path(route).

My doubt is that is it good to include a class into method of another class ?

a simple exapmle:

```
<?php
class router{
    public function get($path,$controller){
        $this -> load($controller);
    }

    public function load($controller){
        include "controllers/".$controller.".php"; // This line is my question
        $obj = new $controller;
    }
}

$router = new router;
$router -> get("/home","homeController");
```

Comment: if you need just only for `load()` than its fine.. else not.

Comment: Yes , `load()` only validates then includes `controller`

Comment: yes its fine.else u need your included class globally than not fine.